# Intuition about Bias in LDV / DLM with Fixed or Random Effects

Tags: time-series, mixed-model, bias, lags

## Problem

I am failing to obtain an *intuition* for why estimates from a time series model that includes a lagged dependent variable as a predictor and random (or fixed) effects for individual units are biased, particularly when the number of time periods is small. And when I refer to estimates, I really mean those associated with other predictors in the model (not the lagged DV or the fixed/random effects) that are likely to constitute the quantity of interest in my typical scenario.

These models may also be called hierarchical/mixed DLM/LDV models. And a simple example looks like this:

$$ y_{it} \sim N(\rho y_{it-1} + \alpha_i + \beta x_{it}, \sigma)$$

As a start, I can see that $y_{it-1}$ and $\alpha_i$ are correlated. I can imagine that $\alpha_i$ might explain away some of the variance $\rho y_{it-1}$ would explain if $\alpha_i$ weren't present. But my existing intuition suggests that these would be balanced based on how well they each explain the data in conjunction with one another. Importantly, I can't see how $\beta$ would be biased by this.

What am I missing?

The following references suggest the bias is real, they make an attempt at explaining why, and they provide solutions. But I cannot wrap my head around the underlying issue. Can anyone provide a not-too-math-focused intuition for the issue?

## References

Anderson, T. W., & Hsiao, C. (1981). Estimation of Dynamic Models with Error Components. Journal of the American Statistical Association, 76(375), 598–606. https://doi.org/10.1080/01621459.1981.10477691

Bhargava, A., & Sargan, J. D. (1983). Estimating Dynamic Random Effects Models from Panel Data Covering Short Time Periods. Econometrica, 51(6), 1635–1659. https://doi.org/10.2307/1912110

Arellano, M., & Bond, S. (1991). Some Tests of Specification for Panel Data: Monte Carlo Evidence and an Application to Employment Equations. The Review of Economic Studies, 58(2), 277–297. https://doi.org/10.2307/2297968

And a 2015 blog post by Paul Allison: https://statisticalhorizons.com/lagged-dependent-variables